# I would like to 410 an entire directory - I deleted my blog

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-410

I had a folder called blog on my site.
I deleted it all permanently.
I would like to 410 it.
How do i 410 an entire folder?

e.g. my site looked like this

```
example.com/blog/mycoolpost1/
example.com/blog/mycoolpost2/
example.com/blog/mycoolpost3/
example.com/blog/mycoolpost4/
```

now posts 1,2,3,4, are dead.

so how do i specify that everything after blog, is permanently deleted. (as well as the folder 'blog' itself)

I need a htaccess line something like this...?

redirect 410 /blog/?(.*)

Comment: How is this related to programming in any way, shape, or form?

Comment: It's not. I'm voting to migrate to SF.

Comment: Writing logical .htaccess files is programming.  This is programming and directly on point.

Answer (score 12):

The [`Redirect` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is the proper way to do this. You should put the following in your virtual host configuration:

```
Redirect 410 /blog
```

If you don't have access to the virtual host configuration, you can put it in the `.htaccess` file in your document root, or I believe you can put the following in the `.htaccess` file in the `blog` subdirectory:

```
Redirect 410 /
```

(I might be off about that, I'm not sure how exactly `Redirect` interacts with path resolution in `.htaccess` files)

Comment: thanks i just did this and this worked:
    redirect 410 /blog

Answer (score 11):

I don't think `Redirect` is the right tool for this, as it only matches the path specified. Just use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/ - [G]
```

Answer (score 5):

The following *.htaccess* would be useful when, for example, you move from a hosting to another and you reorder or delete parts of your web.

As Apache allows human syntax codes I have used **permanent** instead of 301 code, and **gone** instead of 410. You can check http protocol codes here [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10)

I placed the file on my root mynewblogaddress.com folder:

*.htaccess*

```
Redirect permanent /wordpress http://www.mynewblogaddress.com/blog/
Redirect gone /gallery2   
Redirect permanent /directory2 http://directory2.mynewblogaddress.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a rewrite rule in .htaccess to redirect all URLs containing the dead folder "blog" to a custom "Does not exist" error page or whatever. If you want the actual code then I would recommend reading [guide-url-rewriting](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/) to help you figure this out.

Comment: right but i cant find the correct line. something like this, but this isnt workign: redirect 410 /blog/?(.*)

Comment: I would just use something like this: RewriteRule ^blog/(.)*$ error.php [NC,L]. It may not be the exact syntax since its been quite some time since i have used Rewriting, but something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using IIS (7 or above) and stumble across this post as i did, this is how I wound up doing it using the global.asax:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;

    if (app.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.IndexOf("/mydirectory") > -1)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 410; Response.End();
    }
}
```

I happened to be looking for all pages in a directory, but I could have done something similar like targeting all html pages (assuming 410’ing ALL html pages were to be “gone”)