# How can I do a wildcard block in htaccess to a specific URL

Tags: redirect, wildcard

How can I apply a redirect 410 on this specific url:

`https://example.com/shop/`

But leave:

`https://example.com/shop/anything-else`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I would like to 410 an entire directory - I deleted my blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549172/i-would-like-to-410-an-entire-directory-i-deleted-my-blog)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)